# setup vcan interface to be activated on boot

Tags: linux, networking, boot

I want to setup a virtual SocketCAN interface on boot. The following lines do what I want (manually):

```
ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
ip link set up vcan0
```

(or)

```
ip link add dev vcan0 up type vcan
```

I have a method to bring up a *physical* USB CAN interface on hotplugging - I add the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
allow-hotplug can0
iface can0 can static
    bitrate 250000
    up /sbin/ip link set $IFACE down
    up /sbin/ip link set $IFACE up type can
```

I now want to bring up the `vcan` interface on boot, too. So I auto-added the `vcan` module and added those lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto vcan0
iface vcan0 can static
    bitrate 0  # NEEDED but not supported
    pre-up /sbin/ip link add dev $IFACE type vcan
    up /sbin/ip link set $IFACE up
```

But strangely this approach does not work: on boot or when I run `ifup vcan0` I get eighter the following error:

```
Configuring interface vcan0=vcan0 (can)
/sbin/ip link add dev $IFACE type vcan
...
ip link set vcan0 type can bitrate 0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
Failed to bring up vcan0.
```

.. when I add the line `bitrate <somevalue>` or I get

```
Configuring interface vcan0=vcan0 (can)
Missing required variable: bitrate
Missing required configuration variables for interface vcan0/can.
Failed to bring up vcan0.
```

.. when I omit the bitrate setting.

So it looks like I *have to* set `bitrate` and *must not* set it - at the same time.

What am I doing wrong here?

p.s. of course I could simply run the `ip link add ..` on startup but I'd like to use the same approach for both interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

You have to load the vcan module at boot time. Edit */etc/modules* for this and add the line

```
vcan
```

Next, edit /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto vcan0
   iface vcan0 inet manual
   pre-up /sbin/ip link add dev $IFACE type vcan
   up /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE up
```

Finally, restart the interfaces:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

The vcan0 interface should pop up if you type

```
ifconfig
```

in a terminal.